# Did SRAM change/update their 10 speed PowerLink?

Tags: chain, master-link

On a rare occurrence this weekend I managed to completely destroy my SRAM PowerLink. So I went over to my LBS and got a new one; however, when I went to install it, it was super hard to close the link (I ended up giving up after a bit since it would only go half way).

After giving it a night and then trying again, I decided perhaps I had bent the chain links where the PowerLink was, so I bought a new chain. The chain came with the same PowerLink and I had the same problem. Eventually I got it but now I'm most likely going to need to saw it off (just kidding, will need pliers though) if it needs removing.

The only difference I can see is that they went from a gold colored plate to a black one, but it's still 10 speed (and the chain is SRAM as well). Anyone know if they have modified thickness, shape, or anything else?

Comment: How were you trying to close it? Mine wouldn't close unless I stood on the pedal while holding the brakes. Getting it off is another story.

Comment: Check out Sheldon Brown's [Page on chains](http://sheldonbrown.com/chains.html).  It says that for 10 speed chains, the SRAM PowerLink is called a "PowerLock", and that it is single use only.  Posting this as a comment because I have no experience with 10 speed chains or PowerLinks.

Comment: I modified an old pair of reversible snap ring pliers (not the type with changeable tips). With a small notches  ground in the tip to catch the barrel, it installs and removes.

Comment: @RitchMelton I was just doing it by hand, same as I've always done. Usually requires a healthy amount of force, but this was darn near impossible.

Comment: By hand it is impossible. I think the manual says to stand on the pedal while holding the brakes. Either way, that's what works for me.

Comment: I have had difficulty with the ten speed PowerLinks as well. The few that I've tried have been quite difficult to close/open, in comparison to the nine speed ones. And not that I disagree with any information on Sheldon Brown's website, but I have (as well as **all** of my friends) always reused the PowerLinks. Over the years, not a single one has ever been the point of failure on a chain that has broken or snapped.

Comment: As with kibbee, 10 speed chains should be power locks, not power links. The 10 speed quicklinks are normally made by KMC or some other manufacturer. But I think the SRAM powerlocks are supposed to be toolless installation, so the question may still stand.

Comment: I usually position it so the link is on the top of the chain half connected, then slap a peddle down hard with the palm of my hand. Has worked every time so far.

Comment: Also, for removing, get a pair of these. They're for KMC really, but work just as well with SRAM links. http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/kh/en/kmc-missing-link-remover-pliers/rp-prod46600

Comment: ["10 Speed drive trains mandated that each PowerLock is good for a one-time application only"](http://www.sram.com/powerlock)

Answer (score 1):

The new ones for 10-speed and 11-speed are frequently single-use. I buy KMC chains and half-links these days to avoid the possibility of that happening.